# Prove if $ x \to 0 $ then $ \ln x \to \infty $ and...

Tags: limits

While trying to convert limits of $0^0$ and $\infty^0$ forms to $0/0$ form, I came up with a problem.

I will rightly state the context first:

$(a)$ If $x\to 0 , \ y \to 0$ then $z=x^y$ is of ${\bf 0^0}$ form. 
$$\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\implies \ln z = y \ln x} &
\color{blue}{\implies \ln z = \cfrac{y}{\frac{1}{\ln x}} \qquad \left(\cfrac{0}{0} \ \text{form} \right) }
\end{align} $$

$\color{red}{(b)}$ If $ x \to \infty , \ y \to 0,$ then $z=x^y$ if of $\bf(\infty)^0$ form.

$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{\implies \ln z = y \ln x} &
\color{red}{\implies \ln z = \cfrac{y}{\frac{1}{\ln x}} \qquad \left(\cfrac{0}{0} \ \text{form} \right) }
\end{align} $$

All the above information was just for reference. My **main question** is :

> How does $ \color{red}{\ln x \to 0 }$ when $\color{red}{ x \to \infty }$ ? And how does $\color{blue}{\ln x \to \infty}$ when $\color{blue}{x \to 0}$ ?

**EDIT** - I see that I've got my radar wrong. I apologize. Thanks everyone for clearing up my doubts.

Comment: It doesn't.  $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{\ln x}=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{\ln x}=-\infty$.

Comment: $\ln(x)$ doesn't approach $0$ as $x \to \infty$..

Comment: What they said.  However the derivative of $\ln x$ goes to zero as $x$ tends to infinity, and the derivative goes to infinity as $x$ tends to zero (from above).

Comment: Then how did we say it as $0/0$ form in both the equations for (a) and (b) ?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Because if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=\pm \infty$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=0$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. So, why does ln(x) tend to infinity when x tends to infinity?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali I explain in my answer (along with why $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{\ln x}=-\infty$)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hayden for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Comments turned answer)

The actual limits are 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{\ln(x)}=\infty \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{\ln x}=-\infty$$
The reason you get your $0/0$ indeterminant forms are from the fact that if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=\pm \infty$, then we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=0$.

This follows from the fact that if $f(x)$ approaches $\pm \infty$ as $x\rightarrow a$, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, and so $\frac{1}{|f(x)|}=|\frac{1}{f(x)}-0|<\epsilon$.  That is, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=0$.

To see why $\ln(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, first note that $\ln x$ is strictly increasing (to see this, notice it's derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$, which is positive) and given any $M$, we know that $\ln e^M=M$, so this shows that $\ln x$ is unbounded.

(Although this really follows from the same reasoning as showing that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\ln x}=\infty$, you can use this if the proof doesn't make sense and you accept the above limit.) To see why $\ln x\rightarrow -\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^+$ (i.e. from the right, so that $\ln x$ is defined), we replace $x$ with $\frac{1}{t}$; taking the limit of $x\rightarrow 0^+$ is the same as taking the limit $t\rightarrow \infty$, so we have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{\ln x}=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}{\ln \frac{1}{t}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}{-\ln t}=-\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}{\ln t}=-\infty$$